# "Install VMware Tools" greyed out after installing ubuntu 15.04 on vmware player 7.1

Tags: drivers, software-installation, vmware, 15.04, vmware-player

"Install VMware Tools" greyed out after installing Ubuntu 15.04 on VMware Player 7.1. I tried checking "No proxy" instead of default "Windows proxy settings" at "File->Preferences->Software updates-> Connection Settings". This did not work either. Is there a way to install VMware Tools?

Answer (score 38):

I had the same issue.  Like the answer posted before, I had to shutdown the machine and change both the floppy drive and cd drives to "Auto detect" and then power on the machine.

Comment: Also make sure you select the OS correctly in VMWare settings. When the OS is "other", Install VMWare Tools menu is greyed out.

Comment: just adding the cd-rom device back worked for me - floppy not necessary

Comment: Thanks! I did not have to shutdown the machine - the option was non-greyed instantly.

Comment: This works, but why?

Comment: Works, but this is some cringe, VMWare. The answer posted in 2015, we're in 2022 and I just had this issue and it took me an hour to fix this lmao.

Comment: 2025: we'll have to rub a leprechaun in order for `Install VMWare Tools` button to become active.

Answer (score 7):

I unmounted the two ISOs which were mounted because of the Easy Install. After that I was able to push the "Install VMware Tools" button in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

Comment: I think you mean Any supported version of Ubuntu >=14.04 See http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=open-vm-tools-desktop&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: @ByteCommander Well that command did not work for me, but i found another solution and posted it as answer.

Comment: @ByteCommander note that it's a different package name.

Comment: @terdon Is it? Oh, oops... I must have been a little sleepy... Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: +1: Thanks, lifesaver.

Answer (score 3):

You can mount VMwareTools CD image manualy, file path is like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\linux.iso
```

Answer (score 1):

A good solution for Ubuntu as a VMWare guest is to install the open VMWare tools:  This can be done from the command line with the command

`sudo apt-get install --install-suggests open-vmware-tools`

Answer (score 0):

If you add a CD-ROM Drive then you see this option "Reinstall VMware Tools...".

If you don't hava a CD-Rom the option to reinstall the VMware Tools will not be availlable.

Answer (score -1):

What you have to do is simple,

> just start a Guest Machine(your VM)
>
> then you will see that the **VM -> Install VMware Tools** ... option
> is enabled.
>
> Simple clue - when you starting the Guest Machine you see  [this dialog
> box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulmc5.png) (if you have not checked it out earlier) after clicking OK,   **VM -> Install VMware Tools** ... option
> is enabled.

You do not need to change anything other than starting a Guest Machine.(No need to change proxy settings in VMware or unmount an image mounted on your guest machine CD/DVD ROM)